# Comparing and inserting Angular JSon Data

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I cannot figure out why the compare function I have and the insert function I have are not working. I believe one part of it might be because the function is never being called by the button? How exactly can I tell that? It does not seem like alerts are working in angular code.

this is my loginHandler.js

```
(function() {
var app = angular.module('loginHandler', []);

app.controller('LoginController', ['$http' ,function($http){
  var database = this;
  this.validated = false;
  database.dbData = [];

      $http.get('/resources/DatabaseObject.json').success(function(data){
          database.dbData = data;
      });

  this.login = function(credentials){
      loggedInUser = credentals.username;
      validated = true;

      $http.get('/resources/DatabaseObject.json').success(function(data){
          $scope.dbData.push({"123":{"username":"meph","ip":"123","timeLastLogin":"123"}}, "session");
      });
  };

  this.checkSession = function(){
      var ip = "123456";

      if(session.ip.equals(123456)){
          return true;
      }
  };
 }]);
})();
```

Neither of the functions are working.... Not the login or the checkSession.

DatabaseObject.json

```
[{
"users": {
    "cra": {
        "firstName": "Jn",
        "lastName": "it",
        "username": "dmph",
        "email": "ran61@yahoo.com",
        "ip": "192.168.1.1",
        "password": "1234",
        "computerName": "os",
        "prviateKey": "1D3RW12390ASLEWRQ1235"
    },
    "mus": {
        "firstName": "James",
        "lastName": "mh",
        "username": "ch",
        "email": "j61@gmail.com",
        "ip": "192.168.1.1",
        "password": "11212",
        "computerName": "ops",
        "prviateKey": "1D3RW12390ASLEWRQ1235"
    }
},
"session": {
    "123456": {
        "username": "crh",
        "ip": "123456",
        "timeLastLogin": "123456787654"
    }
}
}]
```

and here is my html

```
   <html lang="en" ng-app="gemStore">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>Basic Company Template for Bootstrap 3</title>

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom CSS for the 'One Page Wonder' Template -->
<link href="css/one-page-wonder.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript" src="angular/angular.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="script/headerPanel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/errorHandler.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/loginHandler.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/sessionHandler.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="NameController as name">
<div ng-controller="ErrorController as errorController">
<div ng-controller="LoginController as loginCtrl">
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
<div class="container" ng-controller="CredentialsController as credentials">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Home</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a class="act" href="#about">About</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#services">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Tutorial</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#features">Features</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="download.html" onclick="">Download</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form>
            <ul class="nas navbar-na">
                <li ng-hide="loginCtrl.checkSession(loginCtrl.dbData.session)"><a>User ID:  <input ng-model="credentials.username" type="text"></a></li>
                <li ng-hide="loginCtrl.checkSession(loginCtrl.dbData.session)"><a>Password:  <input ng-model="credentials.password" type="password" onkeyup="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('loginBtn').click()"></a></li>
                <li style="color: red;" ng-show="loginCtrl.checkSession(loginCtrl.dbData.session)"><h2>LOGGED IN AS {{credentials.username}}</h2></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a ng-click="loginCtrl.login(credentials)" method="post" novalidate type="submit" href="index.html" id="loginBtn">Login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </form>
    </div>

    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div>
<div style="color: red;" ng-repeat="login in loginCtrl.dbData">
    <h1>{{login.session}}</h1>
</div>
</nav>
</div>
<div style="color: red;" ng-repeat="errorArray in errorController.errors">
    <h1>{{errorArray.error}}</h1>
</div>
</div>


<div class="header-image">

<div class="headline">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>{{name.name}}</h1>
        <h2>The Impossible!</h2>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not sure if that submit button is ok or not.... Bah! Sorry.... Im really bad at this stuff! I hope someone can help me better understand it, I have been trying different things without anything working.

http://plnkr.co/edit/zYSFmQSU83FMC9UcXhM4?p=preview

Comment: Please provide a plunker/fiddle with a working (or not working) example.. that would help us answer your question

Comment: @user3585563: Did you happen to take a look at my answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `push` doesn't work, because you have `database.dbData`, but trying to push into `$scope.dbData` (which doesn't exist).

The comparing doesn't work, because you compare against `session.ip` (which isn't defined anywhere).

Comment: I did look at your answer and changed that, (which might not be updated 100 percent in my plunker) But it implements scope instead. But I did take it out and try it two ways. I tried $scope implementing it, I tried database.dbData and I tried this.dbData and still nothing. I actually dont think it is the method itself tho.... I cant seem to get an alert to work in the method, for some reason my button is not calling the method.... (I think). http://plnkr.co/edit/zYSFmQSU83FMC9UcXhM4?p=preview

Comment: @user3585563: This is a **[modified plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/PpSRvy9LjG6I55HWSdwS?p=preview)** that gets both functions called (just by fixing the issues pointed out in my answer). I am sorry, to tell you that your app is a total mess :) At least try to get your head around what is the difference between using `$scope` and using `this`+`controller as` syntax.

Comment: Sweet! Its def calling the methods now! Haha. Yeah.... it is def a mess, I honestly am just learning how things work really. I got a small template and started seeing how things interact. So it is super horrible but Its just a learning how things interact! :) And I will def look into the $scope vrs this, because I am still a little confused on it :). Thanks so much tho! No idea if its pushing the data or not but at least it is calling the methods :). I can at least debug more! Thanks for sticking with me through it!

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's because you are using `this.` instead of `$scope.`

Also, you aren't passing `$scope` to your parameters...

`app.controller('LoginController', ['$http' ,function($http){`

It should be:

```
app.controller('LoginController', ['$http, $scope' ,function($http, $scope){
```

And down below you should be using: (not `this`)

```
$scope.login = function () { /* ... */ };
$scope.checkSession = function () { /* ... */ };
```

Comment: Look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/HzrM7/ Open it up in your console. I logged `this` and `$scope`. Change all the `this.` to `$scope.` and you'll see it works all of a sudden. `this` would be used more in a Service.

Comment: Ahh yeah I see, thanks for the info! That helps a lot. But its still not working :( Lol. Grrrr. Could you take a look at my plunker please? I know im just doing something stupid.... I just cant figure it out still :(. http://plnkr.co/edit/zYSFmQSU83FMC9UcXhM4?p=preview

Comment: @user3585563, mcpDESIGNS: Note that using `this` in a controller is also possible/reasonable, if you use the `controller as` approach. On any case, `this` is **not** the same as `$scope`.